# Set value in $scope and use $parsers on it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a field in $scope (i'm new in angularjs terminology), that is linked in html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phone" format-phone/>
```

Format-phone is a custom directive that adds a parser for a view value:

```
.directive('formatPhone', () => ({
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) => {
        if (!ctrl) return;
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(viewValue => {
            var phone = viewValue.substring(0, 12).replace(/* some custom replace */);
            elem.val(phone.replace(/* another custom replace */)));
            return phone;
        });
    }
}))
```

That works perfectly and modify model and view values as intended. I want to add default value to the model in controller code, so i added this line:

```
$scope.phone = '1112223344';
```

But this value is not handled by parser in directive and stays raw until i edit it first time. Can i explicitly call parser on view/model value from controller without writing another initialization directive? Or maybe i can set view value that will be automatically handled by parser?

UPD: Thanks to @potatopeelings i made it better, but this solution looks real bad. Do i have any alternative for calling formatter from parser?

```
ctrl.$formatters.unshift(modelValue => {
    modelValue; // 123456
    return modelValue.replace(...); // View value is now (123)45-6 
});
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(viewValue => {
    var phone = viewValue.replace(...); // (123)456 -> 123456
    elem.val(ctrl.$formatters[0](phone)); // Element value is now (123)45-6
    return phone; // Model value is now 123456
});
```

Comment: it might be happening that your storage.phone is not resolved and before that directive is called. can you show us the controller where you are setting storage.phone?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove this part of real code. This value exist and is being inserted raw, not formatted by parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parsers are meant to convert view values to model values and formatters are used to convert model values to view values.

You need to insert a formatter that converts your (initialized) model value to the view value you need.

Comment: This is nice clarification, but my solution seems to be dirty (updated code in initial post for multiline code). What am i missing?

Comment: Its pretty neat, unless you want to move the change (.replace) to a separate function local to the directive.